# Pourquoi y a-t-il une conjonction ici entre un verbe et son complément?

Tags: conjonctions, syntaxe

Dans la section "Fiançailles pour rire" du roman ["Tchaïkowsky, ou, La nuit d'octobre : 1840-1893"](http://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb356273826), on lit:

> Mais tu avais compté sans la critique: elle se montra très sévère tant pour l'opéra que pour la symphonie. Ton cher Laroche lui-même écrivit des articles peu aimables. Tu te brouillas avec lui et la brouille devait durer deux ans. Et pourtant tu détruisis finalement et la partition du *Voyevode* (quand tu constatas qu'il n'avait pu être joué que cinq fois) et celle du *Fatum*.

Je crois que "la partition du *Voyevode*" et "celle du *Fatum*" constituent le complément du verbe "détruisis". Si cette analyse de la dernière phrase est vrai, pourquoi y a-t-il la conjonction "et" entre "détruisis" et "la partition"? Faut-il comprendre que ce "et" est un erreur?

Sinon, comment analyse-t-on cette phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est une figure de style, un peu ancienne, qui sert à insister sur chacun des éléments cités. Dans le cas présent, on pourrait réécrire la phrase avec *non seulement* ... *mais aussi*.

> Et pourtant tu détruisis finalement **non seulement** la partition du *Voyevode* (quand tu constatas qu'il n'avait pu être joué que cinq fois) **mais aussi** celle du *Fatum*.